# Help with efficient quadtree vertices indexing to avoid redundancy

Tags: algorithm, c++, data-structure, procedural-generation

I am creating a quad tree from ground zero, because I am going to collapse it from bottom up I am refining it with a certain LoD level.

I am using glm for mathematics and opengl for rendering. Instead of pointing to a vertex each quad points to an index from a list of vertex to avoid vertex redundancy.

I start by computing the medians and the center, then I check in the list if any of these vertices exist. For a small amount of vertices this is trivial, however it became
apparent that this strategy is ineffective.

The code for this split is in the [following repo](https://github.com/worldrender/worldrender/blob/343780997086babcdc964c3239e95d001e34e9d2/QuadTree.cpp#L95-L165), if anyone can help me in finding another strategy, even showing me a code snippet, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance